# How to accelerate product of numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I need to product numpy arrays but it's too slow for me. How to fasten it?

```
import time
import numpy as np
N = 2e6
a = np.arange(N)
b = np.arange(N)
c = np.arange(N)
d = np.arange(N)
t1 = time.time()
e = a*b*c*d
t1 = time.time() - t1
print(t1)
```

I tried to product lists but I don't know how to do it without loops

```
list_a = np.array(a).tolist()
list_b = np.array(b).tolist()
list_c = np.array(c).tolist()
list_d = np.array(d).tolist()
list_e = list_a * list_b * list_b * list_d # Error
```

Comment: Using lists will *definitely* not make things faster. I would expect it to make things much, much slower.

Comment: Anyway, this takes around 21 milliseconds on my machine. Just how fast do you need it to be? You are requesting 6 million multiplication floating-point operations - plus all the boiler-plate of moving the numbers around - and home computers operate in the single-digit GHz range... do the math.

Comment: I tested the straightforward approach with lists. It takes about 12 times as long.

Comment: Elementwise multiplication is not defined for lists.  `*` is use for list replication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy` does it very fast, much faster than using `for`s or other ways of Python looping but you can definitely win even more speed using `numexpr`:

```
import numpy as np
import numexpr as ne
N = 2e6
a = np.arange(N)
b = np.arange(N)
c = np.arange(N)
d = np.arange(N)

print(np.array_equal(a*b*c*d, ne.evaluate('a*b*c*d')))
#prints True
```

Here are the timings:

```
%timeit a*b*c*d
%timeit ne.evaluate('a*b*c*d') 
30.7 ms ± 480 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
10 ms ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm guessing numba won't help here?

Comment: Don't know a lot about `numba` yet. The only thing I know is that `numexpr` is really cool when working with simple arithmetics of arrays.